# how to separate single text file into multiple text file by lines using batch?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, text-editing

I have running the following program,

```
@echo off
cls
set /p "filename=type file name>"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r E:\ %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="%filename%" (
echo %%~dpnxa >>path.txt
)
```

I have got a output file `path.txt` which contains,

```
E:\new.txt 
E:\Redmi\new folder\new.txt
E:\windows\new folder\new folder\new.txt
```

I like to have those in separate files like,

`E:\new.txt` in `path1.txt`

`E:\Redmi\new folder\new.txt` in `path2.txt`

`E:\windows\new folder\new folder\new.txt` in `path3.txt`

Comment: Don't use a static value for the target file but instead a (counting) variable or split the result by line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I separate single text file into multiple text file by lines?

Building on the comment by [Seth](https://superuser.com/users/619267/seth), you can use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p "filename=type file name>"
rem initialise counter to 1
set _count=1
for /r E:\ %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="%filename%" (
  echo %%~dpnxa >>path!_count!.txt
  rem increment the counter
  set /a _count+=1
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- I have moved the `setlocal` line in order to stop the variable `filename` leaking into the calling `cmd` shell.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [endlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html) - End localisation of environment changes in a batch file. Pass variables from one batch file to another.
- [for /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) - Loop through files (Recurse subfolders).
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) - Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file.

Comment: As written, this will fail if any part of an output path includes an exclamation point. The solution requires toggling of delayed expansion ON and OFF within the loop. But I prefer to use FINDSTR /N coupled with FOR /F to get the line numbers without the need for delayed expansion (see [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1272862/109090)).

Answer (score 2):

I have a much simpler, and probably faster solution for you:

- Use `DIR /S /B /A-D` instead of `FOR /R` to get the path list. This eliminates the need for an `IF` statement.
- Pipe to `FINDSTR /N`, matching on the beginning of a line, to get the line number for use in output file name.
- Execute the entire thing within `FOR /F` to iterate and parse the results into the line number and the path of each line.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /p "filename=type file name>"
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in (
  'dir /s /b /a-d "E:\%filename%" ^| findstr /n "^"'
) do >"path%%A.txt" echo %%B
```

If it were my script, I would pass the target filename as an argument rather than prompt for it:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in (
  'dir /s /b /a-d "E:\%~1" ^| findstr /n "^"'
) do >"path%%A.txt" echo %%B
```